# Openldap - slap_access_allowed: auth access denied by =0 - Not able to authenticate user

Tags: ldap, openldap

Recently I configured my openldap server to work with certificates. But in process of doing that messed up unsecure port also.
Now, authentication is not working for any user at all.
I am using python-ldap client for creating connection.

```
import ldap
import os
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://<ip>:1389')
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
l.simple_bind_s('uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com', 'mypasspw')
```

I am getting `ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS: {'desc': 'Invalid credentials'}` for the request for all users.

I started ldap server in debug mode and here are the logs.

```
6021594b connection_read(12): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8, got=8
  0000:  30 46 02 01 01 60 41 02                            0F...`A.
ldap_read: want=64, got=64
  0000:  01 03 04 32 75 69 64 3d  73 62 61 74 72 61 2c 6f   ...2uid=myuser,o
  0010:  75 3d 50 65 6f 70 6c 65  2c 6f 75 3d 62 6c 75 65   u=People,ou=myo
  0020:  70 6c 61 6e 65 74 2c 64  63 3d 63 69 65 6e 61 2c   rg,dc=my,
  0030:  64 63 3d 63 6f 6d 80 08  73 62 61 74 72 61 70 77   dc=com..mypasspw
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 70 contents:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f5f1c2fe390 ptr=0x7f5f1c2fe390 end=0x7f5f1c2fe3d6 len=70
  0000:  02 01 01 60 41 02 01 03  04 32 75 69 64 3d 73 62   ...`A....2uid=my
  0010:  61 74 72 61 2c 6f 75 3d  50 65 6f 70 6c 65 2c 6f   user,ou=People,o
  0020:  75 3d 62 6c 75 65 70 6c  61 6e 65 74 2c 64 63 3d   u=myorg,dc=
  0030:  63 69 65 6e 61 2c 64 63  3d 63 6f 6d 80 08 73 62   my,dc=com..my
  0040:  61 74 72 61 70 77                                  passpw
6021594b op tag 0x60, time 1612798283
ber_get_next
ldap_read: want=8 error=Resource temporarily unavailable
6021594b conn=1000 op=0 do_bind
ber_scanf fmt ({imt) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f5f1c2fe390 ptr=0x7f5f1c2fe393 end=0x7f5f1c2fe3d6 len=67
  0000:  60 41 02 01 03 04 32 75  69 64 3d 73 62 61 74 72   `A....2uid=myuse
6021594b daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
6021594b daemon: activity on:
6021594b daemon: epoll: listen=7 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
6021594b daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
  0010:  61 2c 6f 75 3d 50 65 6f  70 6c 65 2c 6f 75 3d 62   a,ou=People,ou=
  0020:  6c 75 65 70 6c 61 6e 65  74 2c 64 63 3d 63 69 65   myorg,dc=my
  0030:  6e 61 2c 64 63 3d 63 6f  6d 80 08 73 62 61 74 72   ,dc=com..mypas
  0040:  61 70 77                                           spw
ber_scanf fmt (m}) ber:
ber_dump: buf=0x7f5f1c2fe390 ptr=0x7f5f1c2fe3cc end=0x7f5f1c2fe3d6 len=10
  0000:  00 08 73 62 61 74 72 61  70 77                     ..mypasspw
6021594b >>> dnPrettyNormal: <uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com>
=> ldap_bv2dn(uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com,0)
<= ldap_bv2dn(uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com)=0
=> ldap_dn2bv(272)
<= ldap_dn2bv(uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com)=0
=> ldap_dn2bv(272)
<= ldap_dn2bv(uid=myuser,ou=people,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com)=0
6021594b <<< dnPrettyNormal: <uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com>, <uid=myuser,ou=people,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com>
6021594b do_bind: version=3 dn="uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com" method=128
6021594b ==> mdb_bind: dn: uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com
6021594b mdb_dn2entry("uid=myuser,ou=people,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com")
6021594b => mdb_dn2id("uid=myuser,ou=people,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com")
6021594b <= mdb_dn2id: got id=0xb
6021594b => mdb_entry_decode:
6021594b <= mdb_entry_decode
6021594b => access_allowed: result not in cache (userPassword)
6021594b => access_allowed: auth access to "uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com" "userPassword" requested
6021594b => dn: [1]
6021594b => dn: [2] cn=subschema
6021594b => acl_get: [3] attr userPassword
6021594b => acl_mask: access to entry "uid=myuser,ou=People,ou=myorg,dc=my,dc=com", attr "userPassword" requested
6021594b => acl_mask: to value by "", (=0)
6021594b <= check a_dn_pat: cn=webadm,dc=webadm
6021594b <= acl_mask: no more <who> clauses, returning =0 (stop)
6021594b => slap_access_allowed: auth access denied by =0
6021594b => access_allowed: no more rules
6021594b send_ldap_result: conn=1000 op=0 p=3
6021594b send_ldap_result: err=49 matched="" text=""
6021594b send_ldap_response: msgid=1 tag=97 err=49
ber_flush2: 14 bytes to sd 12
  0000:  30 0c 02 01 01 61 07 0a  01 31 04 00 04 00         0....a...1....
ldap_write: want=14, written=14
  0000:  30 0c 02 01 01 61 07 0a  01 31 04 00 04 00         0....a...1....
^C6021594f daemon: shutdown requested and initiated.
6021594f daemon: closing 7
6021594f daemon: closing 8
6021594f connection_closing: readying conn=1000 sd=12 for close
6021594f connection_close: conn=1000 sd=12
6021594f daemon: removing 12
6021594f slapd shutdown: waiting for 0 operations/tasks to finish
6021594f slapd shutdown: initiated
6021594f slapd destroy: freeing system resources.
6021594f syncinfo_free: rid=011
6021594f slapd stopped.
```

What I am suspecting is that something is not allowing access to userPassword but I don't know what. I didn't touch olcAccess configs which are:

```
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=webadm,dc=webADM" write
olcAccess: to * by self write by users read by anonymous auth
```

Where I can look further? Kind of stuck now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, looks like you're sending your password over the wire in clear text. Don't do that. Get some kind of TLS going, either [starttls or LDAPS](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ssltls.html) .

Also, `dn.base=""` and `dn.base="cn=Subschema"` are generally controlled by a different backend than the one you'll be applying ACLs to, so you might want to check if you even need those lines where you're putting them.

**To your actual question:**
OpenLDAP ACLs are a first match wins situation. Also, all lines end in an implied `by * none`. So, `olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=webadm,dc=webADM" write` is effectively `olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=webadm,dc=webADM" write by * none`, which means that your following line never gets parse because you've already had a match. (Flow control can change things, but you probably don't need it yet.)

Standard:

```
olcAccess: to *
  by dn="cn=webadm,dc=webADM" write
  by self write
  by users read
  by anonymous auth
```

Flow Control:

```
olcAccess: to *
  by group.exact="cn=ldap-admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by group.exact="cn=ldap-servers,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" read
  by dn.exact="cn=webadm,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com" write
  by * break
olcAccess: to attr=userPassword
  by self write
  by * auth
olcAccess: to attrs=member
  by set="this/owner & this/owner/member* & user" write
  by users read
olcAccess: to *
  by self write
  by users read
  by anonymous auth
```

(Yes, you could make your webadm part of ldap-admins, but really there's so much I don't know about what you're doing or the scope of your system. I also threw in the best common use of sets as an example in case that's handy at some point.)